# Why does this fish script does not run from a launcher?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, fish

I've written the following script, intended to start a daemon and display a Zenity window, then stop the daemon when the window is closed:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

if not ps aux | grep [s]erviio > /dev/null
    set -x JAVA "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"

    ~/Programs/serviio/bin/serviio.sh &

    zenity --info --text="Serviio is running.\nClick OK to stop." --title="Serviio"

    ~/Programs/serviio/bin/serviio.sh -stop
end
```

**If I run the script from a terminal it works just fine.** It also works from a bash terminal, which seems to show that the shebang is working as expected.

However if I create a launcher to point to the script and try to run it, nothing happens. Serviio doesn't start (I can confirm that from `ps aux`) and no Zenity window shows.

I've tried to figure out what it is about the script that's causing a problem but haven't had any success.

- If I remove the test for whether Serviio is running, the script works.
- If I keep the check but make the script display the contents of $JAVA in a Zenity window instead of launching Serviio, it works.

In other words I can't identify any single element in the script that would prevent it from running.

What could be the problem?

Comment: When you launch it from a launcher, does `~` resolve properly? Is it launching as your user?

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, I just tried to make it output the results of `whoami` and `ls ~/Desktop` and both were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why by redirecting the output of the `ps` command to a file. If I run the script from a launcher, grep finds the script itself (which has "serviio" in its name) and so it doesn't execute the code inside "if".

I fixed it by making what grep looks for more specific.

The main cause seems to be that if the script is run directly from a terminal it doesn't appear as a process but if it's run from a launcher then the interpreter (fish in this case) appears with the script as a parameter.